# How does "There" work in the idris tutorial, page 11, section 3.4.4?

Tags: idris

Here is the example from the tutorial, slightly modified for simplicity:

```
data Vect : Nat -> (b:Type) -> Type where
  Nil : Vect Z a
  (::) : a -> Vect k a -> Vect (S k) a

data Elem : a -> Vect n a -> Type where
  Here : {x:a} -> {xs:Vect n a} -> Elem x (x :: xs)
  There : {x,y:a} -> {xs:Vect n a} -> Elem x xs -> Elem x (y :: xs)

testVec : Vect 4 Int
testVec = 3 :: 4 :: 5 :: 6 :: Nil
inVect : Elem 4 testVec
inVect = There Here
```

I can't understand how `There` verifies that the value is correct. 
As far as I understand it, `There` works like a function, so it takes the
element of type `Here`, which when filling in the holes, corresponds to `Elem 3 testVec`, then sets the first value of `testVec` to `y`, and the rest to `xs`. But since, `y` isn't used anywhere, I would except this not to cause any restriction.

However, when I try

```
inVectBroken : Elem 2 testVec
inVectBroken = There Here
```

I get an error:

```
When checking an application of constructor There:
Type mismatch between
        Elem x (x :: xs) (Type of Here)
and
        Elem 2 [4, 5, 6] (Expected type)

Specifically:
        Type mismatch between
                2
        and
                4
```

Can someone explain to me how the above code works (magically?) to restrict `There` to the tail of `Vect`?

Comment: The constructor for `There` does ignore the head of the vector since you must provide a proof that the element is within the tail, which is the `Elem x xs` argument. Your error message is that you cannot construct a `Here 2 [4, 5, 6]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Here 4 (x :: xs)` is a proof that 4 is at the head of `(x :: xs)`, so `x = 4`. `There` takes a proof `Elem 4 xs` that 4 is somewhere in `xs` and so proofs `Elem 4 (y :: xs)`, that 4 is still somewhere down a extended list. That is where the `y` goes to. It does not matter what `y` actually is, it just allows to extend the proof to larger lists. For example:

```
in1 : Elem 4 (4 :: Nil)
in1 = Here

in2 : Elem 4 (3 :: 4 :: Nil)
in2 = There in1

in3 : Elem 4 (8 :: 4 :: Nil)
in3 = There in1
```

By the types you see that not the element 4 changes throughout the proof but the list.